# When I added a plane, the grids are gone

Tags: mesh, object-mode

Whenever I add a plane, the grids is all gone on the top of the plane. But if it's another objects, there is one. I'm a Blender beginner and whenever I watch videos adding plane there's grid while mine doesn't have one. Please tell me why.

Comment: what grid are you talking about? Are you talking about planes that are already subdivided? In that case when you create your object, create a grid, not a plane (shift A > Grid)

Comment: Hi there , Are you referring the floor as the grid?

Comment: you should mention that which grid are you talking about. Specify the scenario with video screenshot and yours one. If you are talking about subdivisions then new plane doesn't have any subdivision. You have to go to edit mode and then subdivide it by selecting subdivide in the menu pressing right click.